# Leave current value if var is empty in a UPDATE query (sql)

Tags: php, sql

I want **not** update a record when the variable is empty when executing a UPDATE query in SQL. However, when the variable is filled, the record should be updated.

So in example, the myAge field in the database have currently a value of 20 (type int).
After executing the following query, the record should still be 20.

```
$age = '';

db_con->query("UPDATE info SET myAge = ".$age." WHERE account_id = 1");
```

Ps: I know I could check if the variable is empty with PHP, but I was wondering If this could be archieved within SQL?

Comment: `if(!empty($yourvariablehere)) { //update }else{ //not update }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an `IF` construct in SQL to check if the value is empty:

```
$age = mysql_real_escape_string($age);
db_con->query("UPDATE info SET myAge = IF('".$age."' = '', myAge, ".$age.") WHERE account_id = 1");
```

If the passed PHP variable is empty, you set the old `myAge`.

Checking in PHP makes more sense, you might save a database query.

The way you are passing that variable to your database is potentially dangerous. If you didn't know about `mysql_real_escape_string`, look it up NOW.

Better yet, start using a database wrapper that escapes values for you.

Comment: This is indeed where I was looking for. Thank you so much for your solution, and also thanks for letting me know about potentially injections, but this was just an example, I always use real_escape_string, thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

I would add the condition into the `where`, if you only care about one field.

It is not clear what you mean by empty.  That could be either `NULL` or a blank string.  My guess is that `myAge` is a number, so `NULL` would be "empty":

```
UPDATE info
    SET myAge = ".$age."
    WHERE account_id = 1 AND myAge IS NOT NULL;
```

You can also do this in the `SET`, if you like:

```
UPDATE info
    SET myAge = (CASE WHEN myAge IS NOT NULL THEN ".$age." END)
    WHERE account_id = 1;
```

This is necessary if you have multiple columns that you want to update like this.  I much prefer `CASE` over `IF()`, because `CASE` is ANSI standard and available in most databases.

Comment: Thanks for the working examples, and also thanks for the little explanation!

Comment: @Piet . . . Oh, I see.  You mean when `$age` is empty, not the column `myAge`.  I though you had a rather strange request.